# prove that $TS = ST$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$ with $\dim(V) = n$.
Let $ T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. 
Assuming that $T$ has $n$ different eigenvalues.
prove that :$$ TS = ST \iff \textrm{each eigenvector of} \ T \ \textrm{is an  eigenvector for }S\textrm{ (maybe with a different eigenvalue)}$$

I managed to prove the right to left direction.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that $TS=ST$, and that $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then
$$ TSv=STv=\lambda Sv $$
so $Sv$ is also an eigenvector for $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

But $T$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, hence each eigenspace is $1$-dimensional. Hence $Sv\in \mathrm{span}(v)$, i.e. $Sv=\mu v$ for some $\mu$, which shows that $v$ is an eigenvector for $S$.