# How can I prove $AB = BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrix, each with $n$ distinct Eigenvalues. Prove that $A$ and $B$ have same $n$ eigenvalues iff $AB = BA$.

Comment: I think you mean "have the same eigenvectors", not eigenvalues. Otherwise, consider two diagonal matrices, which clearly commute but don't necessarily have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763307/prove-that-ts-st/1763317#1763317